# ¿Por qué las cadenas en python (y en Java) son inmutables?

Tags: java, python

La pregunta es muy simple, ¿Por qué las cadenas son inmutables? O más bien: ¿Por que las cadenas no son mutables?. Por lo que sé esto solo se da en Python y en Java...

Comment: Por diseño, porque es más seguro, porque son thread-safe, porque permite crear el String pool más fácil, porque permtie usar Strings con mejor desempeño. Hablo de  Java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La clase/tipo String es inmutable en Java, C#, Javascript, Python, Go... y es una decisión de diseño.

Tiene varias ventajas:

- Pueden compartirse entre métodos, clases e hilos, ya que no se pueden crear efectos colaterales por modificaciones. Por lo que...
- Reduce los errores: ningún método va a modificar inesperadamente su valor. Esto es muy valorado en la programación funcional.
- Funcionan mejor con concurrencia (no crean dependencias entre hilos, al no poderse modificar).
- Hacer una copia es *barato* (sólo tienes que copiar el puntero, no todo el valor).

Tiene algunas contras:

- Concatenar strings es más costoso, por lo que suelen existir clases auxiliares para realizar este tipo de operaciones (StringBuilder en Java y en C#, por ejemplo).
- Un cambio pequeño en un string grande requiere hacer una copia nueva, lo que consume bastante memoria. Esto suele mitigarse porque el original suele desecharse inmediatamente.

En general, se acepta que las ventajas superan a la desventajas, por lo que la mayoría de los lenguajes modernos tienden a crear tipos inmutables para los textos.