# Funcionamiento de Strings literales a la hora de modificarlos

Tags: java

A la hora de utilizar Strings tenemos varias opciones para crear estas cadenas.Tenemos las literales y las de tipo object.Mi duda surge a partir de los literales.
Como es sabido,cuando nosotros utilizamos el atajo para crear Strings como `"texto"`,esta cadena se introduce en un pool interno de Strings al cual al crear cualquier otro tipo de cadena,internamente se verificara que esta no este ya dentro del pool para no tener que gastar recursos en crear de nuevo la cadena que ya teniamos y poder asi reutilizarla.Entonces cuando tenemos dos variables de tipo String creadas de forma literal y con la misma cadena estarian apuntando a la misma cadena.
Viendo el siguiente codigo:

```
String a = "abc" ;
     String b = "abc" ;
     b+="d";
     System.out.println(a);
     System.out.println(b);
```

Como se puede apreciar en la salida, al modificar la variable `b` solo afecta a esta y no a la variable `a` tambien.¿Por que sucede esto si ambas apuntan a una misma cadena?¿Puede ser que porque al llamar `b` y modificarla se crea una nueva cadena dejando asi dentro del pool de Strings tambien la anterior?

Comment: Los `String` son inmutables. Cuando intentas modificar un `String` lo que pasa en realidad es que se crea otro `String` con la nueva cadena provocando entonces que `b` apunte al nuevo `String`, quedando `a` apuntando al viejo `String`.

Comment: No sé si se puede considerar duplicada, pero al menos esta pregunta está muy relacionada con https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443676/por-que-las-cadenas-en-python-y-en-java-son-inmutables