# Problema al usar .append() desde una funcion

Tags: java, funciones, netbeans, java-swing, jframe

Estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto con JFrame.

Todo va perfecto, pero me he conseguido con un problema que no logro arreglar, y es que desda una clase, quiero enviar un dato a una funcion que esta en otra clase para utilizar un .append y agregar un texto a un JTextArea. Sin embargo, al enviar el texto a dicha funcion esta no cumple con agregar el texto, simplemente ignora esta linea y no se por que. Este es un ejemplo del codigo para un major entendimiento:

Desde una clase envio esto:

```
pf.crearTexto("Hola mundo");
```

Y desde la clase del JFrame donde esta el JTextArea (ta_factura) tengo esto:

```
    public void crearTexto(String text){
    ta_factura.append(text);
    System.out.println(text);
}
```

Si lo ejecuto, el System.out hace lo suyo, imprime el text, pero el JTextArea no se modifica.

También probe ya con utilizar el .append en el mismo codigo (fuera de la funcion y accionado por un boton) y en este caso si se ejecuta correctamente.

He intentado de todo, incluso puse ta_factura como global y nada... agradeceria una ayuda

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). El código que compartes es insuficiente para determinar la causa del problema. ¿Podrías compartir el código en el que creas `ta_factura` y dónde defines la propiedad de la clase? ¿Es en la misma clase?

Answer (score 1):

Las instancias de la clase String son [inmutables](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/443676/por-qu%C3%A9-las-cadenas-en-python-y-en-java-son-inmutables/443688#443688), por lo que no puedes modificar `ta_factura`. El método `append` crea una nueva instancia con el valor de la concatenación, por lo que tienes que hacer algo como:

```
ta_factura = ta_factura.append(text);
```